# Subset data based on daterange input

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to subset my dataset based on a daterange input to pass the values in a second widget but it seems that I cannot read the column with the dates properly.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)
x1<-data.frame(
  structure(list(`Approval date Year Trend` = structure(c(1421107200, 
                                                          1424217600, 1424217600, 1425254400, 1425340800, 1425340800, 1425427200, 
                                                          1425600000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426464000, 
                                                          1427241600, 1427414400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 
                                                          1427846400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                 `REGION NAME` = c("Central", "Multinational", "East", "South", 
                                   "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "Multinational", 
                                   "Multinational", "Multinational", "West", "East", "South", 
                                   "South", "East", "East", "North", "Multinational")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                      -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Lending Approvals",
               fluidRow(
                 column(2,
                        dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                                       start  = min(x1$`Approval date Year Trend`),
                                       end    = max(x1$`Approval date Year Trend`),
                                       
                                       separator = " - ")      
                        
                 ),   
                 column(2,
                        
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "reg",
                          label = "Select region",
                          choices = NULL,
                          selected=NULL,
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            `actions-box` = TRUE,
                            `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                            `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                          )
                        )
                 )
                 
      
    )
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  shiny::observeEvent(input$daterange, {
    subsets1 <- unique(
      subset(x1,`Approval date Year Trend` >=input$daterange[1]&`Approval date Year Trend` <=input$daterange[2])
      
    )
    
    shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "reg",
      choices = subsets1,
      selected = subsets1[1]
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to compare the same datatype - see `as.POSIXct`. Furthermore I needed to adjust the column name to `Approval.date.Year.Trend` - use `check.names = FALSE` in your `data.frame` call if you want to avoid the renaming:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)
x1 <- data.frame(
  structure(list(`Approval date Year Trend` = structure(c(1421107200, 
                                                          1424217600, 1424217600, 1425254400, 1425340800, 1425340800, 1425427200, 
                                                          1425600000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426464000, 
                                                          1427241600, 1427414400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 
                                                          1427846400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                 `REGION NAME` = c("Central", "Multinational", "East", "South", 
                                   "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "Multinational", 
                                   "Multinational", "Multinational", "West", "East", "South", 
                                   "South", "East", "East", "North", "Multinational")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                      -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Lending Approvals",
               fluidRow(
                 column(2,
                        dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                                       start  = min(x1$Approval.date.Year.Trend),
                                       end    = max(x1$Approval.date.Year.Trend),
                                       
                                       separator = " - ")      
                        
                 ),   
                 column(2,
                        
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "reg",
                          label = "Select region",
                          choices = NULL,
                          selected=NULL,
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            `actions-box` = TRUE,
                            `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                            `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                          )
                        )
                 )
                 
                 
               )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  shiny::observeEvent(input$daterange, {
    subsets1 <- unique(
      subset(x1, Approval.date.Year.Trend >= as.POSIXct(input$daterange[1]) & Approval.date.Year.Trend <= as.POSIXct(input$daterange[2]))
    )
    
    shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "reg",
      choices = subsets1,
      selected = subsets1[1]
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Alternative without wrapping `structure` in `data.frame`:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)

x1 <- structure(list(`Approval date Year Trend` = structure(c(1421107200, 
                                                          1424217600, 1424217600, 1425254400, 1425340800, 1425340800, 1425427200, 
                                                          1425600000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426032000, 1426464000, 
                                                          1427241600, 1427414400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 1427846400, 
                                                          1427846400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                 `REGION NAME` = c("Central", "Multinational", "East", "South", 
                                   "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "Multinational", 
                                   "Multinational", "Multinational", "West", "East", "South", 
                                   "South", "East", "East", "North", "Multinational")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                      -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Lending Approvals",
               fluidRow(
                 column(2,
                        dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                                       start  = min(x1$`Approval date Year Trend`),
                                       end    = max(x1$`Approval date Year Trend`),
                                       
                                       separator = " - ")      
                        
                 ),   
                 column(2,
                        
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "reg",
                          label = "Select region",
                          choices = NULL,
                          selected=NULL,
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            `actions-box` = TRUE,
                            `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                            `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                          )
                        )
                 )
                 
                 
               )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  shiny::observeEvent(input$daterange, {
    subsets1 <- unique(
      subset(x1, `Approval date Year Trend` >= as.POSIXct(input$daterange[1]) & `Approval date Year Trend` <= as.POSIXct(input$daterange[2]))
    )
    
    shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "reg",
      choices = subsets1,
      selected = subsets1[1]
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```